# Object not moving in the direction it's facing unless rotation is 0 or 180 degrees

Tags: c++, vector, 3d, matrix, rotation

As the title says, the object doesn't move correctly when facing any direction that is not 0 or 180 degrees. This is in 3D space, but the rotation is only on 1 axis (UP), so the object turns left and right.
Here is a paint diagram to help visualize the issue: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60309894/rotationissue.png
While holding the right mouse button down, the object rotates based on the mouse's x delta position.
Here is the code:

```
// Check & calculate rotation.
if (mouse->ButtonIsDown(NiInputMouse::NIM_RIGHT))
{
    int iDeltaX = 0, iDeltaY = 0, iDeltaZ = 0;
    mouse->GetPositionDelta(iDeltaX,iDeltaY,iDeltaZ);
    if (iDeltaX != 0)
    {
        NiMatrix3 mMat;
        mMat.MakeRotation(iDeltaX / 100.0f,NiPoint3::UNIT_Z);
        SetRotate(  GetRotate() * mMat  );
    }
}

// Check & calculate movement.
m_vVelocity = NiPoint3::ZERO;
if ( keyboard->KeyIsDown(NiInputKeyboard::KEY_W) == true)
    m_vVelocity.y++;
if ( keyboard->KeyIsDown(NiInputKeyboard::KEY_S) == true)
    m_vVelocity.y-- ;
if ( keyboard->KeyIsDown(NiInputKeyboard::KEY_A) == true)
    m_vVelocity.x--;
if ( keyboard->KeyIsDown(NiInputKeyboard::KEY_D) == true)
    m_vVelocity.x++;
m_vVelocity.Unitize();

// Move the object.
m_spNode->SetTranslate(GetTranslate() + m_vVelocity * GetRotate() * m_fSpeed * dt );
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming X is left and right in the example image it looks like just your x-velocity is negated. If this is true then swapping the directions for left and right, or negating the x-velocity, should fix it:

```
if ( keyboard->KeyIsDown(NiInputKeyboard::KEY_A) == true)
    m_vVelocity.x++;
if ( keyboard->KeyIsDown(NiInputKeyboard::KEY_D) == true)
    m_vVelocity.x--;
```

Assuming z is out of the monitor this would correspond to a left-handed coordinate system compared to a right-handed in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

I will presume `GetRotate()` returns a 2D vector (or 3D, doesn't really matter so long as `z` is irrelevant) representing the x and y components of the rotation. If so, you probably need a different approach when setting the translation. This is because `m_vVelocity` appears to be local to the object (i.e. positive y is forward, but dependent on the object's rotation).

The following may work for you:

Multiply `GetRotate()` by `m_vVelocity.y`

Next, get the normal to the vector returned by `GetRotate()`. Multiply this vector by `m_vVelocity.x`.

Add these two vectors together to get the final relative translation vector. So now you get something like the following:

```
// Move the object.
Vector2f forwardVec = GetRotate() * m_vVelocity.y;
Vector2f sideVec    = GetRotate().GetNormal() * m_vVelocity.x;
// Obviously above you need a real method to get the normal of GetRotate,
// I used a "pseudo" method.
m_spNode->SetTranslate(GetTranslate() + forwardVec + sideVec );
```

EDIT: Keep in mind a method to find a vector normal differs from 2D space to 3D space (There is no single defined normal for a single vector in 3D space, but there is in 2D space, I used a 2D vector in the example above for this reason)